# Codeigniter Pagination highlights last link when current link is first

Tags: codeigniter-3

I got a strange problem, Codeigniter Pagination highlights last link when current link is first

```
$route['favorite/(:num)'] = 'user/favorite/$1';
$route['favorite/(:num)/page/(:num)'] = 'user/favorite/$1/$2';

$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = "/favorite/$user_fav_id/page";
$config['total_rows'] = $this->user_model->count_user_fav_all_movies($user_id, $user_fav_id);
$config['per_page'] = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = true;
$config['first_link'] = 'в начало';
$config['last_link'] = 'в конец';
$config['next_link'] = '';
$config['prev_link'] = '';
$config['first_url'] = "/favorite/$user_fav_id";
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell CI at what page you are currently at, by providing `uri_segment` :

```
$config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->total_segments();
```

Or

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```